# Lorentz Oscillator and dielectric function: Incorrect formulation in textbook?

Tags: electromagnetism, optics

According to what I was taught in school the relative dielectric function for a Lorentz-Oscillator can be formulated as:

$ \epsilon(\omega)=\epsilon_\infty+\frac{\omega_p^2}{\omega_0^2-\omega^2+j\gamma\omega }$

where $\epsilon_\infty$ is a constant and corresponds to the high-frequency limit for the dielectric function, $\omega_p$ is the plasma frequency, $\omega_0$ is the resonance frequency and $\gamma$ is a damping parameter.
The derivation of this formula is straight forward and can be found, for example in the MIT lecture notes [here](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-007-electromagnetic-energy-from-motors-to-lasers-spring-2011/readings/MIT6_007S11_lorentz.pdf) on page 8.

Now, the authors of the most popular textbook on computational electrodynamic, called "computational electrodynamic - The finite difference Time-domain method" by Allen Taflove and Susan Hagness (3rd ed) claim that the relative permittivity for a Lorentz-medium is

$\epsilon(\omega)=\epsilon_\infty+\frac{\Delta \epsilon \omega_p^2}{\omega_p^2+2j\omega\gamma-\omega^2}$

Even by using the relation $\Delta\epsilon=\frac{\omega_p^2}{\omega_0^2}$, the closest I can come, starting from the 1st equation is

$\epsilon(\omega)=\epsilon_\infty+\frac{\Delta \epsilon \omega_p^2}{\omega_p^2+\Delta\epsilon j \gamma\omega-\Delta\epsilon\omega^2}$

I don't see how an algebraic manipulation allows me to arrive at the equation provided by Taflove. Is there a physical detail I am missing or is Taflove simply wrong or is there another explanation?

EDIT: I just recognized that the $\gamma$ as used by Taflove is not the same as the usual $\gamma$. However, he just calls it "damping parameter" without any derivation. So, by assuming the equations are equivalent these parameters are related by
$\gamma_\text{Taflove}=\frac{1}{2}(\Delta\epsilon\gamma+\Delta\epsilon j \omega-j\omega)$.

Obviously $\gamma_\text{Taflove}$ can become imaginary...So I'm wondering why the hell would somebody come up with such a formulation, where the alternative "damping parameter" loses any physical meaning in contrast to the original one, which might be interpreted as "number of collision" of some particles/quasiparticles having units of 1/s. 
I don't see any benefit from the second formulation at all. Am I missing something?

Comment: Are the definitions of $\gamma$ the same in both cases?

Comment: Good hint. I'm checking it...

Comment: The Taflove expression doesn't seem to resonate near $\omega_0$,  but I'm only using my eye.  I don't have paper and pencil nearby.